# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'layout' when I tried to use app.layout=dbc.Container() to structure the layout of the dash app

Tags: python, html, bootstrap-4, plotly, dashboard

the script I got is:

```
import dash
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import database
from dash import Dash, dcc, html
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc

# create a dash app which is compatible with mobile devices
app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP],
                meta_tags=[{'name': 'viewport',
                'content': 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'}]
                ),
# structure the layout of the web app
app.layout =dbc.Container(
    html.H1(children='Hello Dash'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

the error I got is:

[image: snipshot of the error]

This is so weird, I don't get it why is app a tuple, isn't it class(Dash.dash)?
Please help, any suggestion is strongly appreciated!
*Also I tried removing the layout, but it will just makes app a variable that is a container, which give an error: AttributeError: 'Container' object has no attribute 'run_server'. I tried to change app=dash.Dash(...) to app=dash(...) still doesn't work*

Answer (score 0):

There is trailing comma which is leading to unintended behavior.

```
app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP],
                meta_tags=[{'name': 'viewport',
                'content': 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'}]
                ),
```

This will set app equal to the one item tuple `(<dash.dash.Dash object at ...>,)`. instead of the intended `<dash.dash.Dash object at ...>`.

Similarly, `foo = 1,` will set foo equal to a tuple containing 1 which can be confusing if you haven't seen this syntax before in python.

This should work:

```
app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP],
                    meta_tags=[{'name': 'viewport',
                    'content': 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'}]
                    )
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried without comma it worked!

Comment: You're welcome! when you have a chance, please consider [accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) as this will help people who have the same question as you in the future